# Remove Ember.js script tags from a jQuery selector .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Is there a way in `jquery` to strip out the `<script>` tags that Ember.js generates?

```
<script id="metamorph-107-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<script id="metamorph-125-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>foo-bar-text<script id="metamorph-125-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
<script id="metamorph-107-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
```

I only want `foo-bar-text`. Here is the selector I am currently using:

```
$(".control-group .controls .data").html();
```

Which returns the above.

Comment: where does foo-bar-text come from? from a bound statement like {{foo}}?

Answer (score 4):

Since the question is tagged with `ember.js` and the text `foo-bar-text` is inside a script metamorph tag, to avoid tose tag's you could define it in your templates like

```
{{unbound myProperty}}
```

this way you get the text only with your jQuery selector `.html()` and don't need to strip out the script tag's.

Answer (score 3):

> "I only want foo-bar-text."

You could just use jQuery's [**`text()`**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method then in that case:

```
$(".control-group .controls .data").text();
```

Or, using pure vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('.control-group .controls .data').textContent;
```

Comment: Duh, didn't even think about that. Thanks.

Comment: @Justin Glad to help! I added a pure JS solution (if you need IE8 and before support let me know), but I'd go with text() if you're already using jQuery as it's much better compatibility-wise :) Consider accepting the answer if it helped, thanks!